# How to test a single service in Spring with JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a `@Service` class that gets some properties injected.
I want to write a junit test now that the injection process worked correctly.

How can I define a `JUnit` test without having to load my full application context configuration?

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("${test.property}")
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {  return value; }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {
   @Autowired
   private MyService service;

   @Test
   public void test() {
      assertNotNull(service.getValue());
   }
}
```

But when I run this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to detect defaults, and no ApplicationContextInitializers were declared for context configuration 
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.processContextConfiguration(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:208)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:348)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:305)
```

Comment: Where should the properties be injected **from**?

Comment: application.properties file

Comment: My question was more in the sense of _how_ and/or _why_ should it get it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified the beans file from where to inject the fields that you annotated with @Autowired in your test. You should have something like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
"classpath:applicationContext.xml",
"classpath:junit-applicationContext.xml"
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [unitils](http://unitils.sourceforge.net/summary.html)

It has a module to test spring stuff. It comes in very handy as well if your services interact with a database.